# action class do not passing objects to jsp class ,using struts2 in liferay

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts2, liferay

i'm using struts2 in liferay to create a portlet, i have a submit button that doing an action, in action method i want to fill a private field and pass it to resualt add.jsp but when i want to print that field in add.jsp the value is  null. what is the problem???!!! what should i do????!!

there is no error or exception during run server,build/deploy and executing...

here is my code:

**portlet.xml**

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">

```
    <description xml:lang="EN">IIN Subject</description>

    <portlet-name>MySiteStruts</portlet-name>
    <display-name>MySiteStruts</display-name>
    <!-- struts portlet class -->
    <portlet-class>org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher</portlet-class>
    <!-- The namespace for the actions configured for view mode -->
    <init-param>
        <name>viewNamespace</name>
        <value>/support</value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- The default action to invoke in view mode. -->
    <init-param>
        <name>defaultViewAction</name>
        <value>index</value>
    </init-param>
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </supports>
    <portlet-info>
        <title>MySiteStruts</title>
        <short-title>MySiteStruts</short-title>
        <keywords>MySiteStruts</keywords>
    </portlet-info>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
</portlet>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package namespace="/support" extends="struts-portlet-default,json-default"
        name="subjectview">

        <interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="storeStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
                <interceptor-ref name="store">
                    <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
            <interceptor-stack name="retrieveStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
                <interceptor-ref name="store">
                    <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <action name="index" >
            <result>/html/support/view.jsp</result>
        </action>


        <action name="addsubjects" class="com.test.actions.PowerAction"
            method="navigateToAddSubject">
            <result name="success">/html/support/add.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

**PowerAction.java**

```
package com.test.actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class PowerAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String testString;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        return "success";
    }
    public String navigateToAddSubject(){

        testString = "test object value!!!!!";
        System.out.println(testString);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public String getTestString() {
        return testString;
    }
    public void setTestString(String testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }
}
```

**view.jsp**

```
<%@ include file="/html/init.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<s:form action="addsubjects" theme="simple">
         <s:submit value="submit"/>
</s:
[/code]

[b]add.jsp[/b]
[code]
<%@ include file="/html/init.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<h1>print str:<br></h1>
<h2><s:property value="%{testString}"/></h2>
```

i even use value="testString" in add.jsp but not working too.

Comment: You forgot to mention all the other forums and places where you're discussing the same question already. This would help to eliminate duplicate work

Comment: there is no duplicate, atlist i dont find that, if you find something like this please give me the link

Comment: Of course there's duplicate work: You post in different locations without linking them. The problem might long be fixed (or discussed) in the other places when someone will still worry about the question because it's not obvious, where else you asked (and that the problem has long been solved).

Comment: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/57379372